# How do I convert Localtime to epoch timestamp in powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, epoch

Did look to find conversion of localtime to epoch timestamp but no luck? can someone help me out converting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are after is the `-UFormat` parameter for the `Get-Date` command.

```
Get-Date -UFormat %s
```

The `%s` (lowercase) will give you seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 as outlined in the online section of the `Get-Help` command. Typing `get-help get-date -online` will take you to the list of parameters for the `Get-Date` command.